# Bootstrap - How to create a full screen layout with scrollable columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a full screen layout that takes up 100% of the viewport with a sticky header and footer, and individually scrollable columns in the main content area.

I've experimented with using .h-100 and .flex-grow-1 on various rows and columns but I can't quite get it to work. The closest I've come is to add h-100 to the container and the middle row,  but that pushes the footer off the bottom of the screen.

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 border">Navbar </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 border" style="overflow-y: scroll;">Sidebar </div>
        <div class="col-4 border" style="overflow-y: scroll;">Article list </div>
        <div class="col-6 border" style="overflow-y: scroll;">Article content </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 border">Footer </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I can get it to work with just a single column, but adding more than 1 column breaks the layout in a way I don't understand.

Comment: The documentation shows how to do [a sticky header](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/navbar-fixed/) and [a sticky footer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/). Scrollable columns should just be an overflow setting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the container `d-flex` and then use `flex-grow-1` to make the content area fill the height. You'll also want to use `flex-shrink-0` on the Navbar and Footer so they don't "squish" in height.

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="col-12 border">Navbar </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-2 border" style="overflow-y: scroll;">Sidebar </div>
        <div class="col-4 border" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
            Article list
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 border" style="overflow-y: scroll;">Article content </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="col-12 border">Footer </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/ouc3hddx5i

---

Related:
[Use remaining vertical space with Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744073/use-remaining-vertical-space-with-bootstrap-4)
[Bootstrap 4.0 - responsive header with image + navbar + full-height body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49462256/bootstrap-4-0-responsive-header-with-image-navbar-full-height-body)

Comment: On further testing, this works in chrome and safari, but in firefox the overflow-y: scroll property is ignored.  I think it's related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636832/firefox-overflow-y-not-working-with-nested-flexbox. I've tried adding 'min-height: 0' to the second row but that has no effect.  Any ideas?

Comment: I updated the [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/ouc3hddx5i). For FF you'll need to use min-height:0 on the row and max-height:100% on the scrollable columns.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this a lot for some reason. I separated 'unique' content of my website from the navbar and footer using the `<main>` tag which required addition of
`main {overflow-y: auto}` to your css below `html, body`. Using the the example above as template here's correct html and css.

**HTML:**

```html
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row flex-shrink-0">
            <div class="col-12 border">Navbar</div>
        </div>
        <main class="d-flex flex-fill">
            <div class="row flex-fill" style="min-height: 0">
                <div class="col-2 border mh-100" style="overflow-y: auto">Sidebar</div>
                <div class="col-4 border mh-100" style="overflow-y: auto">
                    <div style="background-color: red; min-height: 1000px">Scrollable article list</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 border mh-100" style="overflow-y: auto">Article content</div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <div class="row flex-shrink-0">
            <div class="col-12 border">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Red div is there only to demonstrate that you can scroll the column. Feel free to replace it with your content.

**CSS:**

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
main {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main

Comment: Your answer needs more clarification. What is ```main```? where is your html markup to illustrate what your css is supposed to do? lastly, the OP needs to make a scrollable column, not the entire "main" view. Provide more details to make your answer usable or even try to explain what your answer fixes.

Comment: You're right. Main tag was the main source of my problems and confusion. I edited the answer to help explain why I used it and how I got it to work. I'm not sure why ```main { overflow: auto; }```  makes such difference. Hope someone with more understanding of bootstrap could answer that.